# Why do some brain-computer interfaces require objects augmentation in order to work?

Tags: brain-computer-interface

[This interface](https://www.next-mind.com/technology/) seems to work only the focused objects have some kind of augmentation (in this case called NeuroTags).

I am wondering about why this is necessary because for the consumer besides being useless, it can also be also annoying.

Is this a way for the interface to reduce some kind of "focus noise" and receive a more clear electromagnetic information from the brain when focusing on a certain object?

Comment: How the interface is actually used can be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_WxaDHNw6I). The augmentation is quite significant IMO.

Comment: Without spending much time looking at things, I presume because they're detecting the tags, which they can control, rather than actual objects in the world, which they cannot.